# How to set a flag `/LFSM:n[KMG]` with robocopy: `Invalid Parameter #8 : "/LFSM:n"`

Tags: windows, powershell, robocopy

I can't find where I go wrong with the `/ LFSM: n [KMG]` flag to `robocopy`. I try to set a floor level at 100 MB. Error I'm getting: `ERROR : Invalid Parameter #8 : "/LFSM:n"`

I tried:

`robocopy "C: \ Users \ test" "C: \ Users \ b2b \ Desktop \ test" / E / XC / XO / V / TEE / LFSM: n M: 100`

`robocopy "C: \ Users \ test" "C: \ Users \ b2b \ Desktop \ test" / E / XC / XO / V / TEE / LFSM: n [M: 100]`

`robocopy "C: \ Users \ test" "C: \ Users \ b2b \ Desktop \ test" / E / XC / XO / V / TEE / LFSM: n [, M: 100,]`

`robocopy "C: \ Users \ test" "C: \ Users \ b2b \ Desktop \ test" / E / XC / XO / V / TEE / LFSM: n [, 100,]`

Comment: The correct syntax for a 100MB floor would be `/LFSM:100M`

Comment: what does this have to do with powershell?

Comment: The script was saved as a `.bat` file and ran in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

As Mathias R. Jessen said, the error was simple. `n` in `/LFSM:n[KMG]` points out where should be a number posted. So for:

- 1 Giga: /LFSM:1G
- 1 Mega: /LFSM:1M
- 1 Kilo: /LFSM:1K